# cannot use object of type stdClass as array when trying to modify a array

Tags: php

I've just read a simple array from my db that was json_encoded, so i decoded it and tried to change a value at index 0, but i get the following error

cannot use object of type stdClass as array when trying to modify a array

any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A JSON-encoded entity can be an object or an array - it appears that in your example it's an object (of type stdClass). You can either reference it as an object

```
$jsonProperty = $decoded->property;
```

save the original JSON object as an array

```
$encodedJson = json_encode((array) $object);
```

or force decoding as an associative array

```
$decodedJson = json_decode($json, true);
```

Personally I'd use the first option and refer to a JSON object with PHP's object access notation for clarity.

Answer (score 3):

by default json strings are decoded as objects and not arrays. 
so you must use json_decode's second parameter. so your call should be like this:

```
$array = json_decode($string, true);
```

Comment: This is *not* default behaviour, `json_decode()` returns data of the type specified by the JSON it's decoding, try `var_dump(json_decode(json_encode(array(1)))); var_dump(json_decode(json_encode((object) array(1))));`